# Mysqld consumes 232% CPU

Tags: mysql, connection, innodb

My mysqld process consumes 232% CPU and and there 14000+ connections

(I'm a little new to this thing but following Stack Overflow for assistance).

top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3112 mysql     20   0 7061444 1.397g  15848 S 232.6  8.9   1138:06 mysqld
```

System:
 Ubuntu 18.04,
 16GB RAM,
 8 Core CPU,
 120GB Disk
 and MySQL version 5.7.25

```
mysql> show status like 'Conn%';
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Connection_errors_accept          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_internal        | 0     |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0     |
| Connection_errors_peer_address    | 0     |
| Connection_errors_select          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap         | 0     |
| Connections                       | 14007 |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And show variables like "%timeout%"

```
mysql> show variables like "%timeout%";
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And mysqld.cnf settings

```
[mysqld]
# Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients
skip-name-resolve
default-storage-engine=InnoDB

max_allowed_packet=500M
max_connections = 256
interactive_timeout=7200
wait_timeout=7200

innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_open_files=5000
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_io_capacity_max=4000
innodb_old_blocks_time=2000
open_files_limit=50000

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 1M
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 50M

tmp_table_size= 256M
max_heap_table_size= 256M

#key_buffer_size = 128M
thread_stack = 128K
thread_cache_size = 32

slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

> Note: Corrected above mysqld.cnf values to match with below reports attached

Additional Info:

- htop:- https://pastebin.com/43f4b3fK
- top:-  https://pastebin.com/rTh1XvUt
- GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/K2fgKwEv (Complete)
- INNODB STATUS:- https://pastebin.com/nGrZjHAg
- Mysqltuner:- https://pastebin.com/ZNYieJj8
- [SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST], [ulimit -a], [iostat -xm], [lscpu] :- https://pastebin.com/mrnyQrXf

Server freezes when multiple db transaction is being carried out. Is there a lock like thing or any configuration flaws?

(Background: This is a WordPress blog and nobody else is accessing it right now. I somehow imported a 115K posts from an old blog but struck here with this CPU ghost)

Comment: `Connections` is a counter of how many connections have been attempted in the past. The number of current active connections is `Threads_connected`, which in your case is 6.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @BillKarwin. But the process mysqld still consume 232% CPU. Is there any flaws in my sql configuration. What might be the reason. Please help

Comment: There's nothing in your config to explain it. The details you pasted don't show any query activity. It might be busy doing background work like flushing buffers or cleaning up the rollback segment. That's only a guess.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on oneclickpaste.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @TELA Please repost your complete SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; TEXT results.  The posted content only has about 150 GV listed and there are normally more than 300 with VERSION near the end.  Thanks for the other posts already available.

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck, Thank for the followup. I've edited above with the information u requested.

Comment: @TELA Additional information request. Post on oneclickpaste.com and share the links. Text results of: D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;, AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis completion.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck. Additional info attached: [SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST], [ulimit -a], [iostat -xm], [lscpu]  https://pastebin.com/mrnyQrXf

Comment: And [SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST] shows 'Query' froze at same 'starting' state when the system got hang

Comment: @tela From what is see in iostat -xm you do have SSD for data storage.  Correct?  and you appear to have 8 CPU's according to iostat.

Comment: Yes 8 CPU, SSD @linode.com. At the beginning CPU was 6 and later upgraded to 8 due to high consumption. But no luck.

Comment: @TELA Do you know why there are more than 5 watchdog, migration, etc  processes running, per TOP results?  Slow Query Log needs to be analyzed to find/improve efficiency.  Many table scans are being used to complete queries, also to be investigated, improved.

Comment: I generated the report when server got frozen after running 5/6 instance of a batch script(wget) to test CPU load and performance.

Comment: Slow queries are there for combination of SELECT queries. But CPU usage noticed at peak during INSERT operation and for that there is no slow queries seems to have logged.

Comment: Thanks for the 6 outputs, but you left out (1) what query/queries were running _during_ the high CPU, (2) SHOW CREATE TABLE for them, (3) slowlog digest, (4) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.

Comment: `Connections` is a counter.  If 14007 connections occurred in one minute, that would be a huge value; If that was for one month, then it is tiny.  `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` would have provided `Uptime` so we could compute the per-second.

Comment: The state of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` is irrelevant; we need the queries.  Were you connected as "root"?  Else you might not see any of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce 90% of cpu cycles used for function every SECOND
innodb_io_capacity=3500  # from 2000 to enable higher IOPS on your SSD devices
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty overhead - count was 3183 in SGStatus
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 277,134
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 778
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance through Global Variables.
Disclaimer: I am the author of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile that includes contact information.

Comment: Thank you @Wilson Hauck for your suggestion and time to go through those long reports.
I will first apply ur suggestion and report back the performance changes. I will utilize your contact information to consult more. Thank you.

Comment: @TELA The best to you as you improve your instance. Looking forward to your contact.

Comment: Unfortunately, mysql.service fail to start after saving these new variables. When I removed them, it starts. And I could not find any google result for "innodb_read_rnd_buffer_size" . Is that misspelled or just 'read_rnd_buffer_size' without 'innodb_'?. Thank you

Comment: @TELA Dang, my humble apologies, the last two leading 'innodb_' should not have been there.  Answer has been updated.

Comment: @TELA Any news on performance after applying the updated Suggestions to your instance?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Wilson Hauck,  I couldn't see  any visible performance changes. Or perhaps I'm unable to measure the difference. I applied some wp hacks like turning off taxonomy term counts etc to reduce slow queries when bulk importing. Now I'm trying to simulate actual(almost) INSERT, SELECT.. queries before moving this to production. Hope, I can come up with a realistic log after that. Thank you

Comment: @TELA  This url will allow you to download Utility Script to measure 10 seconds of activity with RPS calculated.  https://mysqlservertuning.com/products/globalstatusage10sec-sql   Download provided at no charge, checkout will be for $0.00 Order/Invoice.

Comment: Wilson, I rarely find config problems on WP installations.  However, practically no one has fixed the `postmeta` schema -- it is a performance bottleneck.  (It is worse than just being EAV.)  See my answer.

Comment: @TELA - "failed to start" -- sounds like a syntax error.

Comment: `read_rnd_buffer_size` is a MyISAM setting; don't bother with it if you are fully InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames Please review data available from question 959018 at serverfault.com for a MySQL 8.0.13 version for evidence of ALL innodb tables and the high RPS of handler_read_rnd_next for the instance UPTIME.

Comment: @TELA From one of your comments on March 30, 2019. - I will utilize your contact information to consult more. Thank you.-  Please get in touch, when time permits.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - `handler_*` comes from the engine-agnostic code sitting above the Engines.  Read_rnd_buffer belongs to MyISAM; InnoDB either does not have such an animal, or includes it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause of high CPU and poor performance is the poor schema for `wp_postmeta`.  I discuss the remedy [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Meanwhile, "you can't tune your way out of a performance problem".  I did glance at the settings -- all are "reasonable".